# How to return an object from Mono SpringWebFlux

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am using Spring Webflux, and I need to return the ID of user upon successful save.

Repository is returning the Mono

```
Mono<User> savedUserMono = repository.save(user);
```

But from controller, I need to return the user ID which is in object returned from save() call.

I have tried using doOn*, and subscribe(), but when I use return from subscribe, there is an error 'Unexpected return value'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get username from mono<user> on spring boot webflux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56830594/how-to-get-username-from-monouser-on-spring-boot-webflux)

Comment: see this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57019089/returning-monoupdateresult-with-reactive-mongodb-template

Answer (score 5):

Any time you feel the need to *transform* or *map* what's in your `Mono` to something else, then you use the `map()` method, passing a lambda that will do the transformation like so:

```
Mono<Integer> userId = savedUserMono.map(user -> user.getId());
```

(assuming, of course, that your user has a `getId()` method, and the `id` is an integer.)

In this simple case, you could also use optionally use the double colon syntax for a more concise syntax:

```
Mono<Integer> userId = savedUserMono.map(User::getId);
```

The resulting `Mono`, when subscribed, will then emit the user's ID.

Answer (score 2):

what you do is

```
Mono<String> id = user.map(user -> {
        return user.getId();
    });
```

and then you return the `Mono<String>` to the client, if your id is a string

Comment: `User<String> id` should be a `Mono<String> id`

Comment: yes thank for pointing it out, was a bit too fast there. i have edited it

Comment: for readability I'd recommend using method reference: `user.map(User::getId)`

Comment: for readability id say this is more readable, your suggestion is less readable but what i prefer. But since the thread starter doesn't seam to have much experience the more verbose version above is more understandable.